# Convert syntax in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

What's wrong with these statement?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [cfg].[SetBooleanConfiguration]
@key varchar(50),
@value bit
AS
BEGIN

    exec cfg.SetConfiguration @key=@key, @datatype='Boolean', @value=CONVERT(varchar(4000),@value)

END
```

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), I am sure `CONVERT` syntax is written well. But SSMS complain that there is incorrect syntax near `CONVERT`. What's wrong?

**EDIT:**

Statement below run well:

```
exec cfg.SetConfiguration @key='aa', @datatype='Boolean', @value='1'
```

But, statement below gives me error:

```
exec cfg.SetConfiguration @key='aa', @datatype='Boolean', @value=CONVERT(varchar(4000),1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [cfg].[SetBooleanConfiguration]
@key varchar(50),
@value bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @convertedValue varchar(1)

    SET @convertedValue=CONVERT(varchar(1),@value)

    exec cfg.SetConfiguration @key=@key, @datatype='Boolean', @value=@convertedValue

END
```

Comment: `SET @value=CONVERT(varchar(4000),@value)` means nothing. It explicitly convert `bit` into `varchar`, and implicitly convert again into `bit`. But, if i declare `@val` as `varchar(4000)` and change it into `SET @val=CONVERT(varchar(4000),@value)`, it works. Thanks

Comment: Ok, check my update. If you're getting a bit, it is not necessary to use a varchar (4000) to varchar (1) should be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

The datatype for @value is bit?Are you trying to Convert it to varchar(4000)?